# How to plot the cross section of event horizon of hairy kerr black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, kerr-metric

I was growing through the paper "Parameter estimation of hairy Kerr black holes from its shadow and
constraints from M87*" whose link is https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.11417. In the paper it plots the cross sections of event horizon in fig.3 using eq.3.
Can anyone please explain how it is done?

Comment: This question (v1) would be improved if more context were available without needing to follow the link.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! As already said, it would be great if you could add ([edit]) the relevant parts of the paper to your question. For formulas, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: I can write the equation but how to post the figure from the paper? Please someone guides me